# WinUI 3: Binding to `IsChecked` property of `RadioMenuFlyoutItem` stops working after reselecting it for the second time

Tags: c#, winui-3

I've created a test project that allows one to set selected RadioMenuFlyoutItem from the Viewmodel.
I've already created a [bug](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/8532). Also you the sample project can be downloaded from there.

```
<Window
x:Class="Test_menu_radioitem.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Test_menu_radioitem"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<StackPanel x:Name="RootPanel" Orientation="Vertical">
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <local:EnumToBoolConverter x:Key="EnumToBoolConverter" />
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <DropDownButton HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    Margin="0 1">
        <TextBlock Text="Test button"/>
        <DropDownButton.Flyout>
            <MenuFlyout x:Name="AvailabilityFlyout"
                        Placement="Bottom">
                <RadioMenuFlyoutItem GroupName="1"
                                             Text="Active"
                                             Command="{Binding SetUserAvailabilityCommand}"
                                             IsChecked="{Binding Presence, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBoolConverter}, ConverterParameter='Active', Mode=OneWay}">
                    <RadioMenuFlyoutItem.CommandParameter>
                        <local:ContactPresence>Active</local:ContactPresence>
                    </RadioMenuFlyoutItem.CommandParameter>
                </RadioMenuFlyoutItem>
                <RadioMenuFlyoutItem GroupName="1"
                                     Text="DoNotDisturb"
                                     Command="{Binding SetUserAvailabilityCommand}"
                                     IsChecked="{Binding Presence, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBoolConverter}, ConverterParameter='DoNotDisturb', Mode=OneWay}">
                    <RadioMenuFlyoutItem.CommandParameter>
                        <local:ContactPresence>DoNotDisturb</local:ContactPresence>
                    </RadioMenuFlyoutItem.CommandParameter>
                </RadioMenuFlyoutItem>
                <RadioMenuFlyoutItem GroupName="1"
                                     Text="Away"
                                     Command="{Binding SetUserAvailabilityCommand}"
                                     IsChecked="{Binding Presence, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBoolConverter}, ConverterParameter='Away', Mode=OneWay}">
                    <RadioMenuFlyoutItem.CommandParameter>
                        <local:ContactPresence>Away</local:ContactPresence>
                    </RadioMenuFlyoutItem.CommandParameter>
                </RadioMenuFlyoutItem>
                <RadioMenuFlyoutItem GroupName="1"
                                     Text="Offline"
                                     Command="{Binding SetUserAvailabilityCommand}"
                                     IsChecked="{Binding Presence, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBoolConverter}, ConverterParameter='Offline', Mode=OneWay}">
                    <RadioMenuFlyoutItem.CommandParameter>
                        <local:ContactPresence>Offline</local:ContactPresence>
                    </RadioMenuFlyoutItem.CommandParameter>
                </RadioMenuFlyoutItem>
            </MenuFlyout>
        </DropDownButton.Flyout>
    </DropDownButton>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button Click="myButton_Click_Active">Active</Button>
        <Button Click="myButton_Click_DoNotDisturb">DoNotDisturb</Button>
        <Button Click="myButton_Click_Away">Away</Button>
        <Button Click="myButton_Click_Offline">Offline</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

In code-behind for the sake of simplicity

```
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Data;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows.Input;


namespace Test_menu_radioitem
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty window that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            RootPanel.DataContext = new ViewModel();
        }
    private void myButton_Click_Active(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((ViewModel)RootPanel.DataContext).Presence = ContactPresence.Active;
    }

    private void myButton_Click_DoNotDisturb(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((ViewModel)RootPanel.DataContext).Presence = ContactPresence.DoNotDisturb;
    }

    private void myButton_Click_Away(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((ViewModel)RootPanel.DataContext).Presence = ContactPresence.Away;
    }

    private void myButton_Click_Offline(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((ViewModel)RootPanel.DataContext).Presence = ContactPresence.Offline;
    }
}

public enum ContactPresence
{
    Active,
    Away,
    DoNotDisturb,
    Offline
}

public class EnumToBoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (value != null && value.GetType().IsEnum && parameter is string strParam)
        {
            if (Enum.TryParse(value.GetType(), strParam, out var enumParam))
            {
                return Equals(enumParam, value);
            }
        }

        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language) =>
        throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ContactPresence _presence;

    public ContactPresence Presence
    {
        get => _presence;
        set
        {
            _presence = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ICommand SetUserAvailabilityCommand { get; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Presence = ContactPresence.Away;
        SetUserAvailabilityCommand = new RelayCommand(Execute);
    }

    private void Execute(object param)
    {
        var value = (ContactPresence)param;
        Presence = value;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
}

public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<Object> _execute;
    private readonly Func<bool> _canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    {
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<bool> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute();
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        var handler = CanExecuteChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

}

When I set the selected item for the first time it works fine but after picking it again e.g. from Active state to Away the binding doesn't work.

**Steps to reproduce the bug**

1. Launch provided test project
2. Check the selected Menu item
3. Press the button with any other state e.g. Active
4. Check that the state in Menu is correct
5. Press the button with any other state e.g. Offline
6. Check that the state in Menu is correct
7. Press the button with any other state e.g. Active
8. Actual result: the menu item Active is not selected
9. Expected result: the menu item Active is selected

**Expected Result**: the menu item Active is selected

Comment: Not a bug. Make all `Mode=TwoWay` and return `value` in your `EnumToBoolConverter`'s `ConvertBack` implementation.

Comment: @SimonMourier it really works. Thanks a lot!  But I don't understand why? Could you explain it, please?

Comment: If you want constant synchronization between a checkbox (or similar) and an INotifyPropertyChanged-equipped property, you must bind them two ways, so a change to one is always propagated to the other. Note: you don't need your RelayCommand, IsChecked + TwoWay is sufficient. Also, you shouldn't notify property changed if `_presence` is already equal to `value` (saves some cycles and always avoids possible infinite loops).

Comment: @SimonMourier Thanks a lot. I don't want to bother you because you've really helped me and provided solutions works. But why _RelayCommand, IsChecked + OneWay_ don't work? About _isChecked + TwoWay_ it doesn't update in ViewModel `Presence` if we change it in UI. It seems **ConvertBack** should be refactored because `value` is `bool` and `parameter` is `string`. So, I can't get rid of `RelayCommand`. Or I miss something..

Comment: RelayCommand is not related, it's juste useless. This is the code I use and it works fine https://pastebin.com/raw/mF1xwvMy (ps: make sure you update the nuget package to latest WinApp SDK & build tools)